# dplyr & postgresql get group_indices

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, dbplyr

I failed to find a solution to this task:

For simple case let use `mtcars` as an example and let's use a PostgreSQL version of the same data:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)

pgdrv <- dbDriver(drvName = "PostgreSQL")
db <-dbConnect(pgdrv,
                     dbname="DBMTCARS",
                     host="127.0.0.1", port=5432,
                     user = 'postgres')
copy_to(db, mtcars)
mtcars2 <- tbl(db, mtcars)
```

The task is quite simple, get a unique number for each group.
So:

```
mtcars %>% mutate( gi = group_indices(., gear, carb))
```

now I need the same with the DB version

```
mtcars2 %>% mutate( gi = group_indices(., gear, carb))
```

But I got:

> Error in UseMethod("escape") : 
>     no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_PostgreSQLConnection', 'tbl_dbi', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"

I know how to do it with SQL syntax:

> select *, (dense_rank over(order by gear, carb)) as gi FROM mtcars ;

But I would like to do with dplyr grammar or..
how do I use `dbSendQuery` directly in a `tbl_dbi` class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not all functions in the tidyverse would work with the database

Comment: There are an alternative method??

Comment: Then I think I need use `dbSendQuery` in a `tbl_dbi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun comments, not all functions translate. However, this can be made to work to your advantage in some cases.

Here is an approach using `dense_rank` function within tidy verse:

```
approach1 = mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(combined_index = paste0(gear, carb)) %>%
  mutate(gi = dense_rank(combined_index))
```

I am pretty sure both `paste0` and `dense_rank` will translate via `dbplyr` to PostgreSQL, but can not test in my current environment.

Alternatively, you can make use of the fact that when `dbplyr` can not translate a command it leaves it as is. This means you can write some PostgreSQL commands directly into your R. Here is an approach using this idea:

```
approach2 = mtcars2 %>%
  mutate(
             gi = sql("DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY gear, carb)")
        )
```

The idea is that because `dbplyr` does not have a translation for `DENSE_RANK` it will pass this, as is, through to the SQL command. The downside of this approach is that you can not transfer your code easily to an environment that does not have PostgreSQL.

Before executing either of these, you can test whether they will work by checking whether they produce correct SQL syntax as follows:

```
approach1 %>% show_query()
approach2 %>% show_query()
```

Comment: I tried the approach2 but I got an error: ```Error: unexpected symbol in:
Error: unexpected symbol in:"approach2 = mtcars2 %>%gi = (DENSE_RANK OVER"``` also seems there are a `?dplyr::dense_rank` but I didn't unterstand how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated my answer to add the use of the `sql` function into approach2. The testing I have done suggests this will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I want, now I may extend to other situations.